# android - How can I find the owner of /proc/[pid] directory

Tags: android

I want to detect whether a process run by user or not, as I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404296/how-to-retrieve-package-name-and-process-owner-root-user-from-proc-pid-androi) The owner of the /proc/[pid] directory will be the owner of the process. so how can I find the owner of /proc/[pid] directory?

Thanks

Comment: `ls -l /proc/[pid]` and then you have to remove the owner

Comment: how can I run this command in android application?

Comment: use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l /proc/[pid]");`

Comment: the output of this is `Process[pid=5977]` and not the owner of the process!

Comment: @PageNotFound, the result would be the new Process object that represents the native process, how can I get the owner of the /proc/[pid]?

Comment: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls -ld /proc/[pid]` to get the owner of `[pid]`

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -ld /proc/[pid]");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
proc.waitFor();
while (reader.ready()) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String owner = line.split("\\s+")[1];
}
```

Also you can execute `ps [pid]` to get the owner of `[pid]`

Comment: Why most of the time the owner is null? and what this u0_a250 mean as an owner? is it refer to user or other system process.

Comment: If there is no `[pid]`, `line` would be null, `u0_a250` refer to a user.

Comment: they have [pid] but the owner is null, here is the [log](http://pastebin.ca/3131260)

Comment: My code looks the same as yours, did you add a space at the end of `ls -ld`?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the space